# Repository pattern with different local and remote behavior

Tags: android, architecture, repository-pattern

i have a question that needs answers.

I'm trying to implement the Repository pattern for the first time, i successfully implemented it for most parts of my project but now i don't know how to go about solving this.

Basically i need to update the picture of a user, so in my repository i have an

```
updatePicture(userId: Int, picture: File)
```

interface, everything works fine for the repository implementation and the remote data source implementation, but as you know the local data source doesn't use a file to represent the picture of a user, it uses an url string, so in the local data source the interface should be

```
updatePicture(userId: Int, picture: String)
```

but since the concept of repository makes local data source implement the same interface as remote data source i don't know how to solve this.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry, I'm gonna need a little bit more of information. I understand that you have one repository interface and two concrete implementations, one for doing the network request and update the picture in the server-side and another repository with your local cache (which I assume uses a database, Room, ORMlite, Real, something like that). I get what you're saying, but the thing is that you should update your App's cache internally in the repository implementation when you do the request. Please specify which is the flow in which you call both `updatePicture` methods.

Comment: You could have your cache repository, your network repository and a composite repository (which contains two instances of those repositories) and there, you do the network request and update your App's cache. But I need to know how are you calling the `updatePicture` methods. Are you trying to call the `updatePicture` method from the cache repository as soon as you hit the `updatePicture` method from the network repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are two distinct use cases.  The methods accomplish different purposes and so should be different methods: picID = uploadPicture(picture:File) which uploads a picture and assigns it an ID, and updateUserPictureReference(userId:int, picID:int) which assigns that picture id to a user. This lets you more easily assign the same picture to multiple users (i.e. default profile pic), or revert back to a previously used pic.

BTW, I would not assign a URI directly to the user because that locks you into the current directory structure.  Assign an Id and build a predictable URI at runtime using that ID.  If you decide later to restructure the site because you got so successful you need to move them for performance, you can easily do so.  With the URI in the DB, you would have to update appropriate data.  It also makes it easier to debug since during development you can have all links point to one URL, and in production they point somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You could change the signature to use `Uri` instead of `File`:

```
// Instead of this:
updatePicture(userId: Int, picture: File)

// Use this:
updatePicture(userId: Int, picture: Uri)
```

This should work because a `Uri` can represent resources from all sorts of places using different schemes. For example, you can represent a local file resource with a `file://...` URI and a remote resource that can be fetched using HTTP with `https://...`.